# Does a switch statement care about case order?

Tags: arduino, arduino-c++

I have an Arduino Pro Micro that during a loop will read the state of 4 pins and then use that pins to evaluate a switch statement i.e.

```
int bob = DigitalRead(1)+(DigitalRead(2)*2)+(DigitalRead(3)*4)+(DigitalRead(4)*8)
switch (bob) {
case 1:
case 2:
.
.
.
case 15:
}
```

My Question is do I have to go in numerical order?  Does the switch statement actually care about that or will I loose performance by NOT going in order?  Would I be better off grouping them so the code can fall through or using goto case#?  There are several cases where I want to have some common code executed so I was thinking I could group those cases together and only have the code with the break at the end of it in the last case statement.

So I could have cases 4 and 5 grouped together as well as 8 and 10 grouped together or 9 and 11 grouped together.

Is that possible or will it see 10 comes before 9 and quit looking for 9?

Comment: so you use arduino's digitalRead and but you want to optimize the performance of the `case`? let that to the compiler

Comment: @Juraj no I read the pin status using the port names, but I didn't want to get bogged down in the weeds on secondary issues to what my main question is about the order of case statements and if it mattered how they were ordered.

Answer (score 1):

> My Question is do I have to go in numerical order?

No.

> Does the switch statement actually care about that ...

No.

> ... will I loose performance by NOT going in order?

No.

:-)

> Would I be better off grouping them so the code can fall through or using goto case#?

Depends on what you need.

Remember, you need a `break` statement between cases, if you do not want them to run together.

I would say that practically all compilers today are smart enough to optimise `switch` statements. First, make your code readable and maintainable. Later, if there's a performance bottleneck, AND the switch is part of it, then see what other options you might have.